# How to run Expo test suite

Tags: react-native, test-suite, expo

I generated sample expo app, pull the latest https://github.com/expo/test-suite. I run test-suite in the simulator, it shows a spinner which never disappears.

Can you provide me an instruction how to run the tests?

I see some warnings as well while running test-suite.

```html
Warning
Warning: Using unversioned Expo SDK. Do not publish until you set sdkVersion in exp.json
Warning
Warning: 'react' peer depencency missing. Run `npm ls` in /project/test-suite to see full warning.

If there is an issue running your project, please run `npm install` in /project/test-suite and restart.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the repository that you linked is not a "test" suit as you understand it. It is not for testing your app. It exist for the developers of Expo as a tool, to test Expo before new releases of it.

Check out more about unit testing and test driven development;

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_testing

If your goal is to test your own app in you will need a simulator or a development device;

> https://docs.expo.io/versions/v18.0.0/guides/up-and-running.html

Comment: I want to run tests within a simulator in automated way. I'm not interested in clicking through whole app every time I change anything.

Comment: @MarcinGasior have you find any way to do automation testing in simulator  with expo project ?